# Touchpad , wifi and ethernet doesnt work

Tags: networking, drivers, touchpad, ethernet

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot in my laptop. 
It was working good for a few month , but yesterday it started making a weird problem. Wifi doesnt work anymore , I tried to enter in internet by LAN cable , even that does not work. 
When I run the ifconfig command it shows me the details of a Loop Back. No ethernet card or wifi. 
Also , my touchpad does not work. 
I am quite new in linux , but may this be a problem from drivers ?
It all worked well before so I dont understand how this can happen by surprise. 
I saw many posts for this ones , but nothing is working till now. Many solutions has to do with installing packages , but none of those is installing , all are failed to install, I guess cause of my internet missing. 
I dont even know how to post the screenshots , cause I making the question by using Windows 10 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with most of that, but sometime my touchpad stops working and I just open a terminal window (CTRL + ALT + T) and enter `synclient TouchpadOff=0` to turn the touchpad back on.

Sorry I can't help with the other stuff - but hopefully that at least helps with the touchpad!